# How do I create a giant explosion on minecraft bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I create a giant explosion on MCBE?

Comment: Have you tried [TNT](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/TNT)?

Comment: What do you really want? Can you put details into it?

Comment: @fasterthanlight yes what exactly are you looking for? Your question doesn't have many facts about what you want!

Comment: @snoopstick Are you asking me, or the asker?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, here is a simple explanation for explosions. This scale comes from destruction rate. Destruction:  1 being minimal damage, 100 being massive damage, and so on. Simplicity: 1 being very simple (1-2 blocks), 100 being extremely complex, and so on. Cheats means that Cheats is **required** to build this structure.

If you are only here for an explosion and not the destruction, then make sure the TNT is in water.

### One TNT

**Destruction: 1**

**Simplicity: 1**

**Cheats? No**

Just place a piece of TNT on the ground and ignite it. Small explosion; destroys blocks in a 3-5 block radius.

### Cluster TNT

**Destruction: 5-15**

**Simplicity: 2-5, 5-16 (with pistons)**

**Cheats? No**

Place TNT in a *n*x2 arrangement, where n is any number you like. Use redstone to ignite all the TNT simultaneously. This can be improved with a ring of pistons to get a packed, bigger explosion.

### One End Crystal

**Destruction: 5**

**Simplicity: 2**

**Cheats? No**

Place one obsidian or bedrock, and place an end crystal on top. Interact with the end crystal by hitting it with your fist or a projectile.

### Command TNT

**Destruction: 7-30**

**Simplicity: 1-3**

**Cheats? Yes**

Place a Command Block on the ground, set to repeat. Its command will be `/summon tnt x y z`, where `x,y,z` are the coordinates of the place the TNT will spawn. Place a lever or button next to the command block, and activate it.

### Many End Crystals

**Destruction: 15-100+**

**Simplicity: 1-5**

**Cheats? Yes**

Place a repeating command block with the command `/summon ender_crystal x y z`. Place a lever or button next to it. **OPTIONAL:** create a NOT gate running from the lever, going to a command block with command `/summon arrow x y z`, where `x` and `z` are the coordinates of the end crystals.

If you want me to add more, please comment down below. I hope this helps.

Comment: i like the scales you made up :) 
+1

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions for any other blast methods?

Comment: I know that in Java edition you can summon super powerful fireballs, but that's Java. I don't know if it's in Bedrock as well. The only other explosions I can think of are from Creepers and Withers.

Comment: @Quijibo Yes, but I'd say that those are pretty unreliable.